# how to make reponsive model popup in bootstrap version 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i wan to show the popup on few area for html :

[image]

for 1st popup will cover box no 5, 6,9,11

and 2nd popup will cover box no,7,8,10,12

and **when i do re size my browser, it should cover those box :**

for this, i created this : please check the following html in jsfiddle.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
     .margin1 {
            padding-bottom: 5px;
            padding-left: 2.5px!important;
            padding-right: 2.5px!important;
        }

        .fixwidh {
            /*min-width: 295px;*/
        }

        .btnClass {
            width: 40%;
            height: 20%;
        }

        .topmargin {
            height: 10px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .sidemargin {
            background-color: #e0e0e0;
        }

        .mainContent {
            width: 94%;
            background-color: red;
        }

        .verticaltextname1 {
            position: absolute;
            color: gray;
            -webkit-text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(150,150,150,1);
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(150,150,150,1);
            font-size: 20px;
            font-family: Raleway,Arial!important;
            -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            transform: rotate(-90deg);
            top: 20px;
        }

        .topBox {
            min-height: 121px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            margin-right: -20px;
            background-color: grey;
        }

        .topBox2 {
            min-height: 121px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-right: -20px;
            background-color: #c2c2c2;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000000;
            border-top: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
            border-left: 1px solid #f6f6f6;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
            border-right: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
        }

        .topBox3 {
            min-height: 64px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            margin-right: -20px;
            background-color: grey;
        }


        .pClass {
            color: #ffffff;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            margin-top: 82px;
            min-width: 71px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1  col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="pClass">Work History</div>
                        <div>
                            <span class="verticaltextname1">1</span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span class="verticaltextname1">2</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="pClass">Projects</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-10  col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="topBox2">1</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="topBox2">2</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="topBox2">3</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="topBox2">4</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="topBox">5</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="topBox">6</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="topBox">7</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="topBox">8</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="topBox3">
                                9
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="topBox3">
                                10
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="topBox">
                                11
                            </div>
                            <div><a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal">X</a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="topBox">
                                12
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1  col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                    <div class="sidemargin">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1  col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                    <div class="sidemargin">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10">
                    <div style="background-color: black; height: 100%; width: 102%; border: 1px solid red;">
                        Carousel Div
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1  col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                    <div class="sidemargin">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Basic Modal</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <h3>Modal Body</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "when i do re size my browser, it should cover those box". If you really meant "cover" then this not responsive it would be more static. Responsive suggests that it responds to the resize and will resize along with it.

Comment: i mean, when we resize, those box will be responsive also.. and on top there is popup, i need to show

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k8zq2uo0/2/